# Update nsmutableDictionary insert a new key

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

i have a `nsmutabeldictionary` like this

```
   {
        alert = "test from dot net";
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
    }
```

and want to a key 'ID' with value 10 just like

```
     {
        alert = "test from dot net";
        badge = 1;
        sound = default;
        ID  = 10;
    }
```

please help

Comment: Have you tried to write any code to do this? Can you show the Objective-C code you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x1ede8740> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:

It looks as if you actually have an immutable dictionary (note the I suffix).

I imagine your code looks like this:

```
//Even though you are assigning to a mutable object
//The method may not return an mutable dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *d = [someObject getDictionary];
```

You should instead use:

```
NSMutableDictionary *d = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[someObject getDictionary]];
```

Then you can comfortably use:

```
[d setObject:@10 forKey:@"ID"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to call the [setObject:forKey](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutabledictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableDictionary/setObject%3aforKey%3a)

> Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.
>
> ```
> - (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id < NSCopying >)aKey
> ```
>
> **Parameters**
>
> anObject
>
> The value for aKey. A strong reference to the
>   object is maintained by the dictionary. Raises an
>   NSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil. If you need to
>   represent a nil value in the dictionary, use NSNull.
>
> aKey
>
> The key for
>   value. The key is copied (using copyWithZone:; keys must conform to
>   the NSCopying protocol). Raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if aKey
>   is nil. If aKey already exists in the dictionary anObject takes its
>   place.

In your example you can call it like this:

```
[yourMutableDictionary setObject:[NSNumberWithInt:10] forKey:@"ID"]
```

also, remember that you have to pass an NSObject. So you should use `[NSNumberWithInt:10]` instead of just `10`.

Answer (score 0):

To add new object with new Key to Dictionary, you can use SetObject:forKey Method.

Comment: trying this but getting this type of error
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<__NSDictionaryI 0x1ede8740> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: That's `setValue:` you should try `setObject:`

Comment: seems like you have NSDictionary object..You must have NSMutabledictionary if you want to edit it runtime